# Abel was a shepherd, wasn't it a crime?

Tags: animals, meat, parashat-bereishit

Shepherds kill animals, and make food from their meat. It wasn't allowed in the antediluvian era. Abel was a shepherd, wasn't it a crime? Wasn't it at least problematic?

Comment: Shepherds also harvest wool, milk, horns...

Comment: This is a very nice question, but I think it requires a justification for its second half. How do you know that slaughtering animals wasn't allowed before the flood? That's not necessarily a universally-held opinion.

Comment: @ShimonbM The jewish sources I've read until now are consequent about this.

Comment: @ShimonbM which opinions state that slaughtering animals was permitted? I've never heard of any

Comment: Yeah, what the heck that shepherds kill the animals, what about the wool, milk, cheese?! Where is writteen that Abel killed and ate animals?! Ha?

Comment: @havarka It can explain, although it sounds a little bit exceptional.

Comment: @user8558 - if Jewish sources are explicit about this then you should include some Jewish sources in your question. It's not an open verse, but a drash that enables people to conclude that animals were not slaughtered for food before Noah's being commanded in that regard. I wouldn't make the assumption that every person who reads this question is familiar with that interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People were vegetarians before the flood; the change is noted in Gen 9.  But food isn't the only use for sheep.

Hevel probably kept sheep for wool, since after the expulsion from the garden (Gen 3:23) people needed to clothe themselves.  (God made clothes for Adam and Chava (3:21), but it doesn't say he continued to do so for everyone else.)  Additionally, sheep and goats provide milk and goats can be used for (some) labor.  Other herd animals (like oxen) also provide labor, particularly important now that man must till the land to grow his own food.  So there are plenty of uses for animals other than eating them, and if you want to have a reliable supply of wool and milk, and animals for labor, you need to keep herds.

Where Abel got the idea to offer an animal sacrifice is a separate question; there has been no command or suggestion along these lines thus far in the text, but God accepts the offering.

Answer (score 7):

Shepherds move herds. They help raise animals (which provide milk and wool, especially the sheep). There is nothing in the job description of a shepherd that requires killing animals.